# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.InnerNativeModule.installCoreFunctions')

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

Just updated [react native reanimated](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/), [react native gesture handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gesture-handler), and added bottom sheet, I am getting the error above. Any ideas?

```
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.1",
"@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.6.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "2.17.0",
"react-native": "^0.71.13",
```